# Store/retrieve in/from variable number of binary values in a hexadecimal string with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I want to take a hexadecimal string and get an `NSArray` of bit columns (`@[@(1), @(3), @(156)]`) that are NOT `0` in the binary value of that string.

Similarly, I want to take an `NSArray` of bit columns indices `@[@(23), @(52), @(53), @(129)]` and generate a hexadecimal string for those.

Is there a reasonably efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Sure. Write down _exactly_ what you want, then you write code for it. You should post the question again including _exactly_ what input and output you would want.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to convert the string value `@"5000000000000000000000000000000000000008"` into the array value `@[@1, @3, @156]`? You might have the string a different way around of course, i.e. which is bit 0 and which bit 159? What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: @CRD yes that's correct (and vice versa), sorry if the question seems vague. I normally would just do this with an integer, so the only workaround I can think of is to break it up into groups of 4 or 8 or something and concatenate the resulting strings.

Comment: @BenGuild - Why not try it and see if it is inefficient? Each hex char produces at most four values to add to your array, and in the reverse direction at most four values make up a hex char. Design these algorithms and code them. Then, and only then, if the performance is an issue/the algorithms fail think about optimising/asking for help. (No library method for doing this comes to mind, not surprising as its quite a specific need, but that doesn't mean there isn't one.) HTH